Is there a way to only take plaintext input in contenteditable across browsers?
I want my contenteditable component to only take plaintext input and not support HTML, markdown or anything.
I know there exists contenteditable = 'plaintext-only' but it is not yet supported in Firefox.
<p contenteditable="true">
  Some text
</p>


This question is similar to: Contenteditable allowing only plain text. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
